# Swift 2 + Parse How to select all user into Users class

Tags: swift, parse-platform

i use Parse.com to store my data.

I have a class named : Users

In Swift 2 how can i retrieve all users into my Users class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read in Parse documment
try code:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Users")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objs, error) -> Void in
   // objs is array or dictionary
}
```